# Listeners observer design pattern with Handler

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, observer-pattern, android-handler

I was dealing recently with a question I'm not sure how to answer.
I wrote a code example for some AsyncTask that I want to perform. I read somewhere on the net that someone has implemented the AsyncTask and the Handler as inner classes and I wanted to scale that a little bit and make less coupling so I made separated class for those so I can reuse them with more than one Activity.
Because I had to do some different UI things on each Activity I decided to make those activities implement an interface so I can react to each event with same methods.

What I don't understand is why do I need the handler object that will handle the messaging for event occurrence? can't I just use the listeners observer pattern? and then the question that I asked my self and can't understand the answers around the web is what is the difference between my listener observer implementation and the handler object we get from Android.

Here is my code example:

**Activity 1:**

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements MyListener{

    MyAsyncTask myTask;
    MyHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new MyHandler();
        myTask = new MyAsyncTask(handler);
        // initilize the activity views etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void do1(){
        // DO UI THINGS FOR ACTIVITY 1 IN A CALLBACK TO DO1 EVENT
    }

    @Override
    public void do2(){
        // DO UI THINGS FOR ACTIVITY 1 IN A CALLBACK TO DO2 EVENT
    }
}
```

**Activity 2:**

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity implements MyListener{

    MyAsyncTask myTask;
    MyHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new MyHandler();
        myTask = new MyAsyncTask(handler);
        // initilize the activity views etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void do1(){
        // DO UI THINGS FOR ACTIVITY 2 IN A CALLBACK TO DO1 EVENT
    }

    @Override
    public void do2(){
        // DO UI THINGS FOR ACTIVITY 2 IN A CALLBACK TO DO2 EVENT
    }
}
```

Listener interface:

```
public interface MyListener{
    void do1();
    void do2();
}
```

AsyncTask implementation:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    private MyModel m;

    public MyAsyncTask(Handler h){
        m = new MyModel();
        m.setHandler(h);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do something in background with MyModel m
        return null;            
    }
}
```

Handler implementation:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {

    Vector<MyListener> listeners = new Vector<>();

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
            case 1:
                // do something for case 1
                fireMethod1();
                break;
            case 2:
                // do something for case 2
                fireMethod2();
                break;
        } 
    }

    public void registerListener(MyListener l){
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(MyListener l){
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    private void fireMethod1(){
        for(MyListener l : listeners){
            l.do1();
        }
    }

    private void fireMethod2(){
        for(MyListener l : listeners){
            l.do2();
        }
    }

}
```

Some demo model I created:

```
public class MyModel{

    private Handel h;

    public MyModel(){
        // at some point send message 1 or message 2 ...
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler h){
        this.h = h;
    }

    private void sendMessage1(){
        h.obtainMessage(1, null);
    }

    private void sendMessage2(){
        h.obtainMessage(2, null);
    }
}
```

if it is too hard to read the code let me know, and if you don't want to read the code please help me to answer **what is the difference between Handler and listening to events with the observer pattern? are they pretty much different solutions for same problem?** thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between Handler and listening to events with the observer pattern?

The difference is that when you use a listener you call a method synchronously on the same thread. When you use a `Handler` you synchronously add a message to the `MessageQueue` but it is handled only after those messages that are already in the queue.

For example, if you are using a UI handler and you already called `finish()` on the activity and then added your message, it will be inserted after `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`. You can't achieve this with a listener.

The advantage of handlers is that you just add messages to queues and you don't care about threading. You can easily add a message to the UI handler from the background thread. If you use a listener from the background thread, it will be called on a background thread synchronously.

> are they pretty much different solutions for same problem?

No, they are not. Handlers help you to decouple android components which is critical for Android, I think. If you use listeners you will be relying on strong references only which in some cases is not possible because you might leak a memory.

Comment: How can I, with the same handler extended class,  make any kind of action on different activities? Is the way I do it with observable pattern is the correct way to do it? I just want to prevent myself from creating a 'getHandler' duplicated method that instantiate a new handler, inside every activity I want to deal with the messages coming from the handler? Thanks again

Comment: Do you really need the same `Handler` object across activities? Usually it's okay to create a UI handler in each activity, it's not heavy. If you want the same object then you can use a static variable in Application class or maybe base activity. It is safe because the handler will be associated to the UI thread. With regards to your next question, I don't know if you are doing this right because it always depends on the use case. How long is the background operation? Do you need to update the UI? What's the expected behavior if system decides to kill your app?

Comment: Great, I think I got you. The background operation is handled by the user, it is a music player like (MyModel in the code example ) , and user chooses if play or stop it, and when it is playing I need to receive certain messages. And it dies and destroyed with onStop. Any time I receive a message I need to update the UI with some canvas drawing. Maybe it is not that heavy to create handler in each activity and I'll consider this approach.

Comment: Ok. For such apps as a music player one usually use a `Service` component. It allows you to run an operation independently from the UI and also increases the app process priority so that it has more chances to survive when the device is running on low memory. Consider this solution, maybe it will fit your use case better. Thank you.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try to run it as a service, actually it is a metronome player (so I use the AudioTrack), so when I run it as a service I still can use handlers as the messaging platform between the service and UI and take advantage of the messages queue? because it is a metronome i really need to take care of synchronicity and the queue I get from handler is a great thing to do so.

Comment: Yes, services are great in conjunction with handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Handler is UI-threaded component. Usage of simple listener may cause `CalledFromWrongThreadException` if you want to touch some UI.

AsyncTask although have `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`, which are just methods, which are running on UI thread. `doInBackground` runs on separate thread

Comment: `Handler` is not a UI-threaded component. If you create a `Handler` object it will use a thread that you are currently in, that is, if you create a `Handler` on a background thread, it will use a background thread.

Comment: More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html